# Batch Geocoding in R

Tags: r, google-api, geocoding

I found following code to take street addresses from data file and geocode using google api, however when a line returns an error (Warning: Geocoding "Address" failed with error:), the loop stops and file is returned with longitude and latitude only to that line. I need some type of if statement to continue the loop if the api doesnt return results. Any help would be greatly appreciated as file is quite large.

```
# Select the file from the file chooser
fileToLoad <- file.choose(new = TRUE)

# Read in the CSV data and store it in a variable 
origAddress <- read.csv(fileToLoad, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Initialize the data frame
geocoded <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Loop through the addresses to get the latitude and longitude of each address and add it to the
# origAddress data frame in new columns lat and lon
for(i in 1:nrow(origAddress))
{
  # Print("Working...")
  result <- geocode(origAddress$addresses[i], output = "latlona", source = "google")
  origAddress$lon[i] <- as.numeric(result[1])
  origAddress$lat[i] <- as.numeric(result[2])
  origAddress$geoAddress[i] <- as.character(result[3])
}
# Write a CSV file containing origAddress to the working directory
write.csv(origAddress, "geocoded.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: (1) It would help to have an idea what is in `fileToLoad`. (2) Building a frame iteratively is known as "growing objects" and has a special chapter (ch 2) in the [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf); bottom line, it's bad practice. (3) You say there's an error but don't say what the actual error is; please include the actual error text in the question. (4) Error resilience often includes `try` or `tryCatch`, have you tried either of them?

Comment: Hi r2evans, error as follows Warning: Geocoding "NO FIXED ABODE  " failed with error:


Error: Positive column indexes in `[` must match number of columns:
* `.data` has 2 columns
* Position 1 equals 3
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred. code reads csv file with the follwing headers Area Total_Area Office Total_Office Area2 Type Client_Id First_Name Surname Gender addresses. code reads addresses column and converts to longitude and latitude

Comment: Connell, comments can easily be skipped by readers and, if there are a lot of comments, hidden by the interface. Please edit your question and include the error there. Same for your headers, though you know it would be a lot easier to have *usable sample data*; for that, I suggest you include the output from `dput(head(origAddress))` in your question.